# Dynamic graph with chart.js and vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, chart.js

**UPDATED 1**

I have the following bar graph:

[image: grafico de ordenes]

As you can see **I am showing all work orders in finished state that were assigned to users with the operator role.**

To this graph I have added a select that allows me to filter by operator name and then graph, that is **if I choose operator Luis and press the search button, it should only graph Luis operator with all his completed orders, which in this case, you have only 2 orders in finished state.**

I have the query, I have the graph working, I have the select.

**My problem is not knowing how to graph again once the operator is selected from the input select, showing only the orders that the selected operator has.**
I suppose that the solution to this will be done within the script from where I am giving my variables, making the query to the url, etc.

**How can I show on my chart only the operator Luis and all his assigned orders?**

**Is there a method that allows me to re-render the graph?**

**How can I solve this problem?**
For the graph I am using the library chart.js.
 
So far everything stated above:

DashboardController:

In this method I make the query to my database:

```
public function getChart(Request $request)
    {
        $_orders = DB::table('users')
            ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')                        
            ->select('users.id','users.name', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.id) as orders_by_user'), 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')                   
            ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2');
        $_orders->groupBy('orders.user_id', 'users.id',  'users.name',  'model_has_roles.role_id');
        $orders=$_orders->get();

        return ['orders' => $orders, 'users'=> User::NotRole(['Admin', 'Supervisor'])->get()];

    }
```

**As it is a dynamic graph, I am downloading data from my database, I understand that I must make an ajax call, dump the data obtained and then graph, would you help me make the ajax call?**

This is an example, basically here I understand that I must make an ajax call to be able to dump the obtained data and then graph.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('orders');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I honestly don't have much knowledge so I need to move forward, I need someone to guide me with the solution, how implement char.js alongside jajax and jquery

Comment: This is not Q - but more a "freelancer mission". The best idea here is to create a minimal working example (Without so much text + no need for single-page components be more specific in your example - start with "hello world"). Is this example helpful for you? https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/Jjdwvyr. How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ezra Siton  Thank you very much for answering. I will be working with your example is very similar to what I am looking for. I will have to see how I pass those buttons to an input select, and that when graphing only show me the selected option, that is my challenge.

Comment: It's very easy to get index of select menu (build in attribute). Than use this index and show the data related.

Comment: @Ezra Siton I am following your example as it is a dynamic graph I am dumping data from my database, I understand that I must make an ajax call dump the data obtained and then graph, would you help me make the ajax call?